# Extract key as string from list of dictionary

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary

This is for example ,
I have below list of dictionary which has 1000's of dictionary and need key string for each dictionary as row

The example is just for understanding purpose

```
Corp =[{'boy':1},
       {},
       {'kids': 3, 'parents' :4}]
```

I need below output in pandas with one columns as key strings

O/P

```
|boy         |
|            |
|kids,parents|
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `join()` to combine the list of keys into a comma-separated string. Use a list comprehension to get everything into one big list.

```
result = [','.join(d) for d in Corp]
```